# Is Lagrange's mean value theorem is valid on $x^{1/3}$ in $[-1,1]$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have a function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ in interval $[-1,1]$ , is lagrange's mean value theorem valid here ? $f(x)$ is continuous in this interval but there's a confusion in it's derivative. What about it's derivative at $x=0$ it looks like not defined as $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$.

Comment: @HerbertQuain You're confusing the Intermediate value theorem (which only needs continuity and states roughly that a function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ takes on all values in $[f(a),f(b)]$ ), and the Mean value theorem (Which needs existence of derivative and states that there is $c$ at which $f^\prime(c)$ has the slope of the secant $[a,f(a)],[b,f(b)]$.

Comment: Ha, my bad ! English is not my first language and I always misunderstand the english names of these two theorems.

Comment: @HerbertQuain Don't worry I taught the theorems for 5 years as a TA and still usually have to go check Wikipedia to figure out which is called what.:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The theorem requires the function to be differentiable in $(-1,1)$, and it isn't so you can't use it. However, there is a point where $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$:
$$ f'(c)=\frac{1}{3 \sqrt[3]{c^2}} = \frac{f(1)-f(-1)}{1-(-1)} = 1 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt[3]{c^2}=\frac{1}{3} \Leftrightarrow c=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{27}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange's mean value theorem in it's standard form can not be applied since as you correctly point out $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ does not have a finite derivative at $0$. To be perfectly honest off the top of my head I can't think of a function which has the behaviour of $x^\frac{1}{3}$  (i.e. has an infinite derivative at one point and is differentiable everywhere else) yet does not satisfy the conclusion of the mean value theorem. Which should not be taken to mean there are no such functions though.

Comment: Try $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^{1/3}, & x \geq 0 \\ (-x)^{1/3}, & x < 0 \end{cases}$. (This is just the reflection of $x^{1/3}$ for $x>0$ through the $y$ axis.) The MVT on $[-1,1]$ would give you a point with zero derivative, but there is no such point. This is in some sense "typical", it is a case where an extremum happens at a critical point where you do not have differentiability. $g(x)=1-|x|$ would be a similar example with a corner instead of a cusp.

Comment: @ian Right except this does not behave like $x^\frac{1}{3}$ in the sense that it doesn't actually have a derivative at $0$ at all. Not even an infinite one. The left and right limits will be $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ respectively (I think) since there is a cusp at $0$. On the other hand $x^\frac{1}{3}$ does not have a cusp and it's smooth when considered as a curve ( this just follows from the fact that it's just a reflection of $x^3$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Hmm...

Comment: @ian Actually for this particular situation (i.e. a function $f(x)$ which has an infinite derivative at one point and whose derivative is nowhere $0$ and which has an inverse) you can show the mean value theorem holds by looking at the inverse. I'm pretty sure you can actually do this in general if the curve is smooth but the proof of the general case escapes me since the global nature of the theorem makes it quite tricky (you need to somehow smartly partition the function since you can have a function which has many vertical and horizontal tangents.)